# Use LINQ to select distinct properties in Lists of Lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct

I want to use LINQ to select a unique list of strings, stored as a List, inside an object. This object is itself stored in a List inside another object. It's hard to explain, here is an example:

```
public class Master
{
   public List<DataCollection> DateCollection { get; set; }
   public Master() { this.DateCollection = new List<DataCollection>(); }
}

public class DataCollection
{
   public List<Data> Data { get; set; }
   public DataCollection() { this.Data = new List<Data>(); }
}

public class Data
{
   public string Value{ get; set; }
   public Data() {  }
}
```

Using the Master class, I want to get a list of unique Value strings in the Data class. I have tried the following:

```
List<string> unique = master.Select(x => x.DataCollection.Select(y => y.Value)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Can somebody show me how it's done?

Comment: So you want the distinct `Data` of all your `DataCollection`'s data stapled together?

Comment: make distinct go in inner parantheses such as master.select(x=>x.DataCollection.Select(y=>y.value).Distinct()) .  Your metohd right now gets distinct master not distinct inner values

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do that like this, directly using the public `DateCollection` member:

```
var unique = master.DateCollection
    .SelectMany(x => x.Data.Select(d => d.Value))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

The key being `SelectMany` to "flatten" the selection.

Answer (score 11):

[`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) projects a list of lists into a single list:

```
List<string> unique = master
    .SelectMany(x => x.DataCollection.Select(y => y.Value))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```